# c++ error: else without a previous if

Tags: c++, if-statement, syntax-error

Just making a small program to begin c++ and the compiler says that there is an else without an if in reference to the while loop in main, though it is clearly not the case and I cannot see why. It works fine if I remove the while loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int number;

int arithmetic(int num)
{
 if(num > 20)
  num = num * 5;
 else 
  num = 0;
 return (num);
}

int main()
{ 
 int wait;
 cout <<  "I will take any number providing it is higher than twenty" << endl;
 cout <<  "and I will multiply it by 5. I shall then print every number" << endl;
 cout <<  "from that number backwards and say goodbye." << endl; 
 cout <<  "Now please give me your number: " << endl;
 cin >> number;
 int newnum = arithmetic(number);
 if (newnum != 0)
  cout << "Thank you for the number, your new number is" << newnum << endl;
  while(newnum > 0){
   cout << newnum;
   --newnum;
  }
  cout << "bye";
 else
  cout << "The number you entered is not greater than twenty";
 cin >> wait;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Only if you had read that tutorial carefully...

Comment: I read it perfectly, several times. Go to http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/ They wrote it there with no brackets.

Comment: @DamianStelucir In case you did not notice, the page you quote said: "If we want more than a single statement to be executed in case that the condition is true we can specify a block using braces { }:"

Comment: @DamianStelucir Only if you had read that tutorial **carefully**...

Answer (score 3):

You are missing brackets. You have

```
if (newnum != 0)
cout << "Thank you for the number, your new number is" << newnum << endl;
while(newnum > 0){
cout << newnum;
--newnum;
 }
cout << "bye";
else
cout << "The number you entered is not greater than twenty";
```

while you should have:

```
if (newnum != 0)
{
   cout << "Thank you for the number, your new number is" << newnum << endl;
   while(newnum > 0){
   cout << newnum;
   --newnum;
   cout << "bye";
}
else
    cout << "The number you entered is not greater than twenty";
```

If you have more than one operation in if statement, you should always use brackets. If you have just one, you can as well omit them (as in this "else" statement).

Answer (score 2):

You need a `{` after `if (newnum != 0)` and a `}` before the `else`.

Answer (score 2):

This type of construction is wrong:

```
if(something)
  line1;
  line2; // this ; disconnects the if from the else
 else 
  // code
```

You need something like

```
if ( something ) {
  // more than one line of code 
} else  {
  // more than one line of code
}
```